# html tables to worksheets excel (keep html format )

Tags: data-export, excel

My excel files have images so when i export to xml type, these images are losed.

I have 2 visualforce pages need export excel file which contains 2 page into 2 sheets. 
( I tried use excel program  to exports to html, it divide to 2 sheets to **2 html files.** when read per sheet it will load that page to read
 The excel file need have all content because It can't connect to server to read page - need login)
I export each page to excel file successfully. 
I can't export it into 1 file has 2 sheet.
I searched on internet but they convert to **XML**.
What should i do now? 
I realy stuck!

1) Is it posible display images in excel's xml?
2) How to export 2 sheet from html table???

Comment: When you do the export, are there links to the images in the cells where you expect them to appear?

Comment: The link is in there. I open it by notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you're having is that the Visualforce pages are (as would be expected) displaying the images using hyperlinks. You'll need to download the images to your local machine using the hyperlinks to determine their location in your Salesforce Database.

One you have them on your local machine, you should be able to easily replace the hyperlinks with the images or "re-link" them to the locations where you've stored them locally on your machine.

Comment: Thank you for anwsering my question. 
1) As i known, XML file can't display image ( i tried , export excel to xml or put the link in tag of xml file). i just google it. I will try again.
(it's ok with html type, excel will download images when open files)
2) I'm newbie in salesforce and web programer, Could you tell me: 
Is it impossible if i use jquery to download 2 pages (in html) to local machine, and then create new file to link these files (display as many sheet)

Comment: Have never tried downloading pages with jQuery, but if you can grab the images and other content that way, off-hand, I don't see any reason why you couldn't reconstruct the tables using jQuery. What you can't do is link to the images stored on the Salesforce Servers, you'll need to download all content to your local machine. Hope that answers your question.